# What is the state of ES6 JavaScript, is it approved, what other steps are required?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Regarding the approval process of the next version of Ecmascript - where are we at in the implementation process - and how does anyone know?

Is there somewhere that EcmaScript progress is tracked?
Is there a W3C link that will give an announcement or is this something that will happen?

Does anyone know the current state of ES2015, ES2016, ES2017 approval process, and what steps or milestones exist to measure feature progress and browser adoption?

Comment: ECMAScript 6 compatibility table: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a temporary situation.

Comment: If you cannot find information otherwise, this would be more appropriate for https://esdiscuss.org/.

Comment: No @FelixKling that link does not help, and no this is not a temporary situation - as we will be in the same state for ES6 and ES7 - this is a valid question that the entire industry needs to know about.

Comment: *"that link does not help"* Meaning you asked a question there and didn't get an answer? It usually takes a bit, sometimes one or two days. *"this is not a temporary situation - as we will be in the same state for ES6 and ES7"* No we won't. When it comes to the transition to ES7, ES6 will have been finalized and approved. There won't be any confusion about where ES6 is (which is what your question is about). Once ES6 was approved you have to come back and update your answer.

Comment: *"this is a valid question that the entire industry needs to know about"* I'm not arguing against that. I'm just stating that Stack Overflow is not the right place for such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Committee process should be articulated for anyone that is looking for this information regarding ES6 release, or ES7 and ES8 releases of JavaScript.

This is the link: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#final_draft

Here is part of the Specification Process.

1. It states that ES6 was in Final Draft.
2. It was submitted to General Assembly Members.
3. It came from a series of Release Candidate Drafts
4. And Prior Drafts before that.
5. There was a Meeting of the GA to vote on approval of ES6 June 2015
6. And it was approved June 2015.

The Specification Milestones for future releases are:

A. Release Candidate Drafts
B. Final Drafts
C. Submissions for Approval
D. Approval

There is also a process for adding and vetting new language features:

ES Feature Maturity Stages:
0. Strawman
1. Proposal
2. Draft
3. Candidate
4. Finished

Subsequently, there are steps in final adoption and release of the standard among browsers. Those milestones are relevant to this question when we need to know what the adoption rate is. That is where the compatibility table comes in: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Also the process has been updated with the Release Train concept.
Causing a name change:
ES2015 is ES6
ES2016 is ES7
ES2017 is ES8

Answer (score 6):

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#final_draft

> This is the final draft of ECME-262 6th Edition, The 2015 ECMAScript Language Specification. This draft has been submitted to the Ecma General Assembly members for their review and consideration. The GA will vote on approving it as a Ecma standard at their June 2015 meeting.
>
> Assuming GA approval, it will still be possible to make very minor editorial corrections in the published version. So, please continue to report any bugs or typos at bugs.ecmascript.org

Answer (score 2):

As of today, ES6 Spec is Approved!
You can find it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)